# How to find out what's automatically processing a file when placed in a folder

Tags: windows, automation, files

When I place a file in a particular folder, it gets deleted within a few seconds.  I think there is some process that is doing something with the data in the file and then removing the file.  What's the simplest/fastest way I can find out what's accessing the file after I drop it in the directory?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably enabling auditing and see what user account is accessing the file...that might help:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784387%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Or you can run wireshark or Process Monitor:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 and watch real-time what is occuring.  That would be the way I would go...starting with Process Monitor.

Comment: Process Monitor for sure